# Image loses anti-aliasing after height transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code for my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the jQuery that handles the image shrinking:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('nav').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

Here is the CSS for the image shrinking:

```
.navbar-header img {
    height: 80px;
    transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
nav.shrink img {
    height: 60px;
    transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

The problem is that the image loses its anti-aliasing in all browsers except Firefox when it does the transition. The image goes all jagged and looks terrible.

I've tried the following fixes:

- adding .show() and .hide() to the image in the jQuery
- -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
- outline: 1px solid transparent;
- -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
- -webkit-perspective: 1000;
- making the image background a solid color rather than transparent

Literally nothing works. I've seen themes do this with no anti-aliasing issues and I'm lost on why this is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe there is much you can do about this. When the size or ratio of the displayed image is not that of the original file, then the browser will resample it. The quality of the image will then entirely depend on the resampling method the browser uses.

Comment: Why doesn't the logo on this theme lose the anti-aliasing when it is resized (scroll down to watch it resize)? http://themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/full_screen_preview/9228123

Comment: That site uses a responsive stylesheet. The source of the image changes for each different resolution - it's not resized on the fly.

Comment: A fiddle always makes things easier. Anyway, try adding `transition:translate3d(0,0,0);` to the image.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm talking about the logo changing sizes when the user scrolls down the page, not its responsive style declarations. Go to the URL I posted, look in the top-left corner at the "canvas" logo, and then scroll down the page. It changes sizes and does not lose anti aliasing.

Comment: @Skatch, please make your comment the answer and I'll accept it. What you posted worked.

Comment: I see now I made a typo in that comment, should be `transform` instead of `transition`  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when animating images, chrome needs hardware acceleration for anti-aliasing. Use the following line on the image element:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Some more on the [subject](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css).